# Redirect according to conditions

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

```
jQuery.getJSON('https://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js', function() {
 var country = geoip_country_code();
 var city = geoip_city();

   if (city == 'Ashburn' || city == 'Palo Alto' || city == 'Menlo Park' || country == 'IN')
{
window.top.location = "https://www.google.com/";
 } else if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

} else {
    top.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
}
   });
```

I want to redirect user according to. As you see in code but its not working.

First check if user is from which city or country then check if users is from mobile or desktop and redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href` , like below:

```
window.location.href = "www.google.com"
```

**NOTE:**

[window.location mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Comment: @user3304678 Which browser are you using? Mobile orDesktop. Give the full details, what did not work?